# Is there a way to enable both unix socket and http in consul?

Tags: consul

I am currently running consul agent as a service in the VM and it works well with http or unix:/// option, but I have a requirement where I need both http and unix socket has to be enabled... Is it possible? please let me know your thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`addresses`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#addresses) key supports specifying a space-separated list of addresses to bind to. You can use the following configuration to have Consul listen on an IP address as well as a Unix socket.

```
# config.hcl
addresses {
  http = "0.0.0.0 unix:///tmp/consul-stackoverflow-example.socket"
}
```